# Reactjs if element has child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const element = (e) {
  alert(e.haschildNodes())
}


<div className='results' onChange={element}>
  <p>results</p>
</div>
```

the results div will have the p element based on the input of other element. myquestion is how can check if the results div has child elements or not 'the p tag'.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800). Would you mind sharing a [mcve] and exactly what's the goal behind this solution you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        const len = ref.current.querySelectorAll('*');
        console.log('results children length: ', len);
      });
      observer.observe(ref.current, { childList: true });
    }
  }, [ref])

  return (<div className='results' ref={ref}>
    <p>results</p>
  </div>);
};
```